# How to rearrange AUTO_INCREMENT Column in SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am making an Android App in which there is a List of Users.
And for that I am having a Users table where i am maintaining users' id using AUTO_INCREMENT

db.execSQL("create table Users (u_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, u_name TEXT , u_username text)");

Now my problem is that when i am trying to delete a user from database through ListView.

But after deleting the sequence order is like this : 1,2,4,5,7

So how can i rearrange the AUTO_INCREMENT column to : 1,2,3,4,5 like this.

How to query this thing in SQLite database.

Please help Me, i am stuck.

Comment: and this order (`1,2,4,5,7`) is just fine, why would you want to change it? on your street there are houses with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc up to 20, yours is 5, then someone rich bought houses 2, 3 and 4, demolished them and built a huge house on those parcels, now should your house number be changed to number 3? of course not

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT will always increment by one from the last inserted record, no matter if that record still exists or not. if a sequential ordering without gaps is what you want, auto incremental ID is not the proper way to achieve that. Add another int field where you manually keep track of this ordering.

Comment: As like in MySQL there is a way to achieve that like this

Reset the auto increment field
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = number;

so is there any way in SQLite like this?

Comment: Let me explain you the whole scenario :

I am having a ListView UsersListView(On Activity 1).
Where i am displaying details of Users like:
Full Name , Username & Age.

OnItemLongClick i am opening another Activity where i am displaying User's details &
allowing user to edit their details and delete the whole user.
So deleting is on another Activity.
And i am storing those details into Database.
So i have to pass something over there via OnLongClickListener through which i can update and delete those Users.

Comment: Thats why i need a Unique id to do that.
and OnLongClick i ll only get the position which will varies after deleting the rows.
So thats why i want to reset the ids into database.
Now got my problem?

Comment: @Shreedhar How are you doing update and delete operation? Using ListView position as id of record in db? Why not to get actual id of the record along with other details from db and use that id to do these operations(update and delete operation)?